# Matlab - matrix addition in for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a 7x21 matrix called A. Within this matrix there are three equally sized 7x7 submatrices. I call them B,C and D, where B = A(:,1:7), C = A(:,8:14) and D = A(:,15:21).

How can I produce a matrix E which is also 7x7 matrix where simply B, C and D are added up, i.e. E = B+C+D.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic code to get such an output -

```
N = 3; %// Number of submatrices
[m,n] = size(A) %// Get size [no. of cols must be multiple of N
E = reshape(sum(reshape(A,m*n/N,[]),2),m,n/N)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Divakar! That was exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: +1 You can do with just one `reshape`: `E = sum(reshape(A, [m n/N N]), 3);`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, good suggestion! Well recently I have been trying to keep it 2D wherever possible. Would be interesting to see which one works better.

Comment: @Divakar I thought one `reshape` less would pay off. I think the reason is that `sum` is faster along first dimension, isn't it? Do you remember the reference for that?

Comment: @LuisMendo Well my impression thus far has been that `squeeze` and `permute` aren't cheap, but `reshape` is. Regarding `sum` along `dim3`, I think I had one discussion with you that if we could avoid `squeeze` that way, then it's worth it. Does that ring any bell? :)

Comment: @Divakar Yeah, I seem to recall that. But I thought there was some kind of canonical answer about this

Comment: @LuisMendo Hmm canonical stuff on this? Nah, can't remember anything other than comments. Could be some question on `SO` before I joined `SO` maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60923/discussion-between-luis-mendo-and-divakar).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what's going to be more straightforward and concise than

```
E = A(:,1:7) + A(:,8:14) + A(:,15:21)
```

Unless you need an expression that generalizes in some way you're not describing...

Comment: You are right, my problem description was somewhat sloppy. Nevertheless, Divakar got what I was driving at!